# How to "unzip" then slice and find max for elements in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, zip, max, slice

I have a list of lists and need to find a way to find the max of the numerical portion of element `[0]` of each list.  I know it'll involve slicing and finding max and think it'll involve the `zip(*L)` function but don't really know how to get there.  For example, what I have is a list of lists that looks like this:

```
L = [['ALU-001', 'Aluminum', 50], ['LVM-002', 'Livermorium', 20], ['ZIN-003', 'Zinc', 30]]
```

and need to find the largest numerical portion (ex. 001) of the first elements.

Comment: To return the whole list element using your criteria, try `max(L,key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('-')[-1]))`

Answer (score 2):

You can do unzip using zip(*L), and since the numerical comparison is same as comparing alphabetically, so you don't have to convert the numerical part to int if the number have a **fixed width**.

```
>>> max([i.split('-')[1] for i in zip(*L)[0]])
'003'
```

Comment: `int` is only unnecessary because the numerical parts have a fixed width. If this extended to mixed widths, `int` would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
max(int(subl[0].rsplit('-',1)[1]) for subl in L)
```

This will return `3`. If you want to print `'003'`, then you can do this:

```
print "%03d" %max(int(subl[0].rsplit('-',1)[1]) for subl in L)
```

**Explanation**:

As you seem to already know, `max` takes a list of numbers and returns the largest one. This is almost correct: `max` takes any **interable** and returns the largest element. A generator is an iterable and takes O(1) space as opposed to a list, which takes O(n) space.
You can also use a list comprehension to create a generator (called a generator comprehension), which is what I have done.

```
(int(subl[0].rsplit('-',1)[1]) for subl in L)
```

is the same as:

```
def myGen():
    for subl in L:
        elem = subl[0]
        myNum = elem.rsplit('-', 1)
        myNum = int(myNum)
        yield myNum
max(myGen)
```

The `subl` iteration iterates over the sublists of `L`. `subl[0]` gets the 0th element of each sublist. We then call `rsplit('-' ,1)`, which splits the string into two parts, at the occurrence of the first `-` from the end of the string; the splits are presented in a list. The 0th index of this list is what was on the left of the `-` and the 1th index is what was to the right. Since the number was on the right, we take `subl[0].rsplit('-',1)[1]`.
At this point, we only have the string `'003'`, which we want to turn into an `int` for the purposes of `max`ing. So we call `int(subl[0].rsplit('-',1)[1])`. And that's how this generates all the required numbers, which `max` then pulls the biggest one out of

Comment: It would probably help to break this down into pieces, because even an experienced Python dev would have to think to understand that expression; a novice may not be able to figure it out at all.

Comment: @abarnert: I've edited in some explanations. What do you think?

Comment: Very thorough, and nicely explained.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` is its own complement!

```
L = [['ALU-001', 'Aluminum', 50], ['LVM-002', 'Livermorium', 20], ['ZIN-003', 'Zinc', 30]]
zip(*L)[0]
#=> ('ALU-001', 'LVM-002', 'ZIN-003')
```

However, it's unnecessary to zip here. Instead, most python sort/max/etc. functions take a `key` argument:

```
max(L,key=lambda (a,b,c):int(a.split('-')[1]))
#=> ['ZIN-003', 'Zinc', 30]
```

The `max` function considers the value generated by applying `key` to each element of `L`.